# PHP retrieve values recursively from JSON

Tags: php, json, recursion

I am getting JSON object from cURL API and I need to recursively go through the JSON and print the treeview of the arrays.

Here is a look at the JSON object:

```
{"message":"OK",
"records":{"Company INC":
    [{"positionName":"CEO",
      "seniorName":"John Doe",
      "seniorId":"1035",
      "seniorSex":"male",
      "child":[{"positionName":"Assistant to CEO",
                "seniorName":"Jane Doe",
                "seniorId":"427",
                "seniorSex":"female",
                "child":[{"positionName":"Assitant to assistant",
                          "seniorName":"James Doe",
                          "seniorId":"1370",
                          "seniorSex":"male"},
                         {"positionName":"2nd Assistant",
                          "seniorName":"Jana D. OE",
                          "seniorId":"1049",
                          "seniorSex":"female","child": ...
```

Etc. As you can see in the records section, some people have children and I need to print them as well.
This is the function I use after I json_decode (true) the JSON object.

```
function recurseTree($var){
    $out = '<li>';
    foreach($var as $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $out .= '<ul>'.recurseTree($v).'</ul>';
        }else{
            $out .= $v." ";
        }
    }
    return $out.'</li>';
}
```

This works great except it prints all of the information from JSON, I would like to print on one line only the seniorName and positionName.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://nl1.php.net/json_decode) ah it seems you (might) already do as you use `is_array` in that case how is your situation different from any other piece of code that uses an array to retrieve properties and skips some other?

Comment: Why don't you use json_decode? You must first decode your json into an object or array

Comment: You want to output smth like <li>"John Doe, CEO"</li> ... <li>"James Doe, Assitant to assistant"</li>, am i right?

Comment: I already mentioned that I use the function after I use json_decode. S Korolev -> yes, that is the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to skip a certain set of properties. Or use it to define keys you do not want to skip:

```
$keys_to_skip = array('some', 'keys', 'to', 'skip');

function recurseTree($var, $keys_to_skip){
    $out = '<li>';
    foreach($var as $k => $v){ // Note I take the key here
        if(in_array($k, $keys_to_skip)) { continue; }

        if(is_array($v)){
            $out .= '<ul>'.recurseTree($v, $keys_to_skip).'</ul>';
        } else {
            $out .= $v." ";
        }
    }

    return $out.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether you have a large amount of array keys or not, you may want to reverse the "$keys_to_skip" to "$keys_to_use" and use if(!in_array($k, $keys_to_use)) { continue; }, whichever means you need to maintain a smaller array list! You also probably want to not concatenate it all into a string but instead into an array so that you can use a custom sort to ensure seniorName comes ahead of positionName.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your code however is not returning anything, it somehow skips everything even though I define in the skip array only seniorID and seniorSex

Answer (score -1):

```
public static JsonNode getValuefromJsonRecursively(String jsonString, String jsonKey) {
        JsonNode result = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JsonNode object = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
            result = getValuefromJsonRecursively(object, jsonKey);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static JsonNode getValuefromJsonRecursively(JsonNode input, String jsonKey) {

        JsonNode result = null;
        if (input instanceof ObjectNode) {
            Iterator<String> keys = input.fieldNames();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keys.next();
                JsonNode value = input.get(key);
                if (key.equals(jsonKey)) {
                    result= value;
                    break;
                }
                if (value instanceof ArrayNode) {
                    result= getValuefromJsonRecursively((ArrayNode) value, jsonKey);
                }
                else if (value.isObject()) {
                    result= getValuefromJsonRecursively((ObjectNode) value, jsonKey);
                } 
            }
        } else if (input instanceof ArrayNode) {
            input = (ArrayNode) input;
            int arraySize = (input).size();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                JsonNode a = (input).get(i);
                if (a instanceof ArrayNode) {
                    result= getValuefromJsonRecursively((ArrayNode) a, jsonKey);
                }
                else if (a.isObject()) {
                    result= getValuefromJsonRecursively((ObjectNode) a, jsonKey);
                } 
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The user have asked solution in PHP not java.